# Apache proxy server difference in response for ErrorDocument redirection

Tags: linux, apache, redirect, proxy, errordocument

I have a  apache proxy server setup in windows and linux.
The configuration of httpd.conf are same in both windows and linux .Here is the conf

```
<Location "/">
  #adding Error document details
   ErrorDocument 502 ${serverroot}/file.html
   ErrorDocument 503  ${serverroot}/file.html
   ProxyPass "https://someurl.com"
   ProxyPassReverse "https://someurl.com"
</Location>
```

So whenever the proxypass throws the error 502/503 , it redirects it to error document i.e to the page file.html.

When I checked the access logs , found the difference in the response in windows and linux systems.

In windows --- > POST / HTTP/1.1" 302

In Linux  ----- > POST / HTTP/1.1" 502

Why there is difference in response ?? 
Error code 302 is redirection code .Why windows is sending redirection error code but not linux ???